# There is no output for the table JAVA GUI

Tags: java

Hello im looking for someone to help me solve this problem. the table doesn't want to exceed. is there any way that can help this problem

```
   public class GameStart extends JFrame{


private JPanel p1,p2;
private JButton boom1,boom2;
private ImageIcon image[] = {new ImageIcon("build/image/scissors.png"),new ImageIcon("build/image/paper.png"),
    new ImageIcon("build/image/rock.png"),new ImageIcon("build/image/spock.png"),new ImageIcon("build/image/lizard.png")};
private JTable table;
private String score[] = {"0","1"};
private String total;
public GameStart(String title)
{
    setTitle(title); //set the title
    setBounds(100,100,800,500);
    p1 = new JPanel(); //create panel 
    p1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    setContentPane(p1);
    setSize(900,900);
    p1.setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true); //make it visible
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
   
    JLabel gametitle = new JLabel("Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock"); //Title
    gametitle.setHorizontalAlignment((SwingConstants.CENTER));
    gametitle.setBounds(1,11,781,14);
    p1.add(gametitle);
    
    JPanel titlecolor = new JPanel(); //background color for title
    titlecolor.setBackground(Color.orange);
    titlecolor.setBounds(0,0,900,30);
    p1.add(titlecolor);
    
    JLabel Rounds = new JLabel("Round 1"); // text for rounds
    Rounds.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    Rounds.setBounds(0,80,782,14);
    Rounds.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.BOLD,15));
    p1.add(Rounds);
    
    JLabel player1name = new JLabel ("Player 1");//Name for player 1
    player1name.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    player1name.setBounds(0,300,200,14);
    p1.add(player1name);
    
    JLabel picture1 = new JLabel(image[0]); //Image for player 1
    picture1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    picture1.setBounds(50,250,400,200);
    p1.add(picture1);
    
    JLabel player2name = new JLabel ("Player 2");// Name for player2
    player2name.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    player2name.setBounds(650,300,200,14);
    p1.add(player2name);
    
    JLabel picture2 = new JLabel(image[3]);//Image for player 2
    picture2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    picture2.setBounds(400,250,400,200);
    p1.add(picture2);
    
    
    
    boom1 = new JButton("BOOM!"); //Boom Button for player 1
    boom1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    boom1.setBounds(700,350,80,16);
    p1.add(boom1);
    
    boom2 = new JButton("BOOM!"); //boom button for player 2
    boom2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    boom2.setBounds(50,350,80,16);
    p1.add(boom2);
    
    JLabel scissors = new JLabel(image[0]); //scissors image
    JLabel paper = new JLabel (image[1]); // paper image
    JLabel rock = new JLabel (image[2]); // rock image
    JLabel spock = new JLabel (image[3]);// spock image
    JLabel lizard = new JLabel (image[4]);// lizard image
    
    JLabel winscore = new JLabel(score[0]);
    JLabel losescore = new JLabel(score[1]);
    JLabel totalscore = new JLabel (total);
      
    String [][] playername  = {{"Team 1:"+ player1name,""+winscore,""+losescore,""+winscore,""+totalscore},{"Team 2:"+ player2name,""+score[1],""+score[1],""+score[1],""+totalscore}};//create row for table
    String [] column = {"Player","Round 1","Round 2","Round 3","Total"}; //create column for table
    table = new JTable(playername,column); //set the table with row and column variables.
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500,50));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setBounds(50,700,80,16);
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    p1.add(sp);
```

i got problem with my table. it doesn't execute the table part.
someone help me to solve this please.
I already find the solutions on the internet but it still the same.

Comment: Don't use a null layout!!! Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short, do **not** use the null layout manager (`p1.setLayout(null);`)

otherwise, since you are not using any layout manager, you must set the position and size of every component - this is not being done for the scroll pane. Add something like:

```
    ...
    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table);
    sp.setBounds(10,10,200,100);  // values MUST be changed as needed
    p1.add(sp);
```

and since the frame is already visible, call `validate()` after adding all components:

```
    ...
    p1.add(sp);
    validate();
```